# Publish-Subscribe Event Handlers - Static vs. Singleton

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, event-bus

I'm currently designing an event bus, and as it currently stands, methods wishing to subscribe to events must be `static`, with their declaring classes registered directly as `Class` objects. However, I'm aware that Guava includes [an event bus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) which accepts an `Object` during registration and prefers instance methods as subscribers. Is there an advantage to the latter system? In practice I'm not sure of the difference, as the `Object` registered is effectively a singleton. I'd be interested to hear the pros and cons.

Comment: There is a **massive** pro. Objects hold **state** so you might want to (and often do in practice) register the same object multiple times with different parameters. I would suggest that you use an existing, tested, implementation rather than rolling your own. This isn't a trivial problem...

Comment: Ah, I see. Regarding implementation, I already have a system mostly written; I was mostly curious as to the reasoning of Google's design choice and whether I should take it into consideration for my own project.

Comment: And when you want to add asynchronous handling? Distributed messaging? Queue persistence? Any number of other features - will you roll this yourself too? Test this yourself? I would **strongly** recommend that you use an existing implementation, especially if your current version only accepts `static` methods...

Comment: Did you think in test cases?